# Custom Street View in V2

Tags: flash, html, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-street-view

Currently there's only documentation and tutorials for creating custom street view using Google Maps API v3 on google website which uses HTML5 only!

Has anyone tried to create custom street view using Google Maps API v2 ?? ..eventually I want this example to be in google maps api v2 (Flash): https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple

Now the reason i want to use flash (google maps api v2) is that it gives much better rendering quality, smooth and no lagging compared to google maps api v3 (hml5 canvas) especially in fullscreen.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: v2 is deprecated and could be retired per Google's deprecation policy (at the time) as early as May 19th, 2013 (less than a year from now).

Comment: I am aware of the deprecation, i want to use flash for the meantime until the browsers are more stable with rendering custom street view images... or if there's any alternatives for Custom Street View please let me know. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

There is no custom street view panorama option in V2. As you can see by checking the API Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference

Anything undocumented is against the terms of service.

If you're set on using V2, then you might want to look for custom panorama solutions, such as 360 Cities